# mongo group with order

Tags: php, mongodb, group-by, sql-order-by

i try to run such code

```
$collection->group(array('goods_id'=>1, 'server_id'=>1), array('count' => 0, 'ip'=>'', 'date'=>''), 'function (obj, prev) { prev.count++; prev.ip=obj.user_ip; prev.date=obj.time_download }')->sort(array('count'=>1));
```

without sort works, with sort not work
any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB does not yet support grouping and ordering in a single query. Until it can, you can do two things:

1. Sort the result of the group query in your code ('client side')
2. Run a MapReduce and run a query, with sort(), on the collection that the MapReduce outputs

Comment: What kind of example are you looking for?

Comment: Sort the result of the group query in your code ('client side')- you mean put result array to function php sort?

Comment: Yes. If the values of your array consists of just a scalar value (i.e. not an array), you can use asort(), otherwise you can use  usort()